# VBA Worksheet Loops

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm currently working with a workbook containing 34 different tabs.
I'm trying to extract Monthly Data from each of the tabs  and Transpose it into daily figures for each specific city.
I have put all the dates within the year 2019 as columns in order to present it as daily figures. (See example in img below)

[image: How My template looks like]

Each tab contains data for each specific city.
I always want to extract the data present on row 20 from column 4 to 15 in each tab for each specific city. ( see 2nd image below highlighted in yellow)

[image: Data that Im trying to extract]

```html
Public Sub CreateArray()



Dim myArrayOfMonths(11) As Double

Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim otherSheet As Worksheet

Dim i As Integer

Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim j As Integer


Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
Set otherSheet = currentWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

i = 1

For Each currentSheet In currentWorkbook.Worksheets

r = 20
j = 0

For c = 4 To 15

    myArrayOfMonths(j) = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c)
    
    j = j + 1

Next c

Debug.Print myArrayOfMonths(0)

   
  i = i + 1

Next currentSheet


Set currentSheet = Nothing
Set currentWorkbook = Nothing







End Sub
```

In my code I'm trying to run through all of the tabs with a loop
and with a 2nd loop check the date (row 16, column 4 to 15) and extract it on my template (Similiar to a vlookup) Unfortunately, it never passes through the first tab as i=0 always for some reason.

Could you please advise?

Comment: You set `i = 1` at a few places, but never use `i` in your code. Also get rid of the `Activesheet` see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: Do you realise that this `ActiveSheet` never changes - is this the cause of the problem? You should probably be referring to `currentSheet`.

Comment: @Luuklag I ve tried incremeting the i but it still outputs the same thing

Comment: @DavidGorgan ofcourse, you don't use the `i` anywhere in your code to reference worksheets. So incrementing does nothing but changing the value of `i`.

Comment: Keep in mind that as you go through all the sheets, eventually your `currentSheet` is going to equal the `otherSheet`.  You may want to qualify that.

Comment: Your dates are screwy.  On your output tab you are using Day/Month/Year, and showing dates daily.  On your city data tab, your row 2 dates appear to be in Day/Month/Year, but Row 16 dates are in Month/Day/Year.  Pet-Peeve: There should only be one date format Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second.

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to do something like this?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PopulateOutput()

    Dim outputSheet As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer

    Set outputSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

    ' starting at index 2 since output sheet looks like index 1
    For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i)
            outputSheet.Range("B" & i & ":M" & i).Value = .Range("D20:O20").Value
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort, but I need the same figure for january all across the january dates, then the same for february and so on, similiar to a vlookup. Thank you for try though!

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

```
Public Sub CreateArray()

    Dim myArrayOfMonths(11) As Double

    Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
    Dim otherSheet As Worksheet

    Dim r As Integer
    Dim c As Integer

    Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook
    Set otherSheet = currentWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")

    For Each currentSheet In currentWorkbook.Worksheets

        r = 20

        For c = 4 To 15
            myArrayOfMonths(c - 4) = myArrayOfMonths(c - 4) + currentSheet.Cells(r, c)
        Next c

    Next currentSheet

    otherSheet.Range("B1:M1").Value = myArrayOfMonths

    Set currentSheet = Nothing
    Set currentWorkbook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `currentSheet.Cells(r,c)` instead of `ActiveSheet`

or use `currentSheet.Activate` and then `myArrayOfMonths(j) = ActiveSheet.Cells(r, c)`, but try to avoid ActiveSheet.

Comment: Please avoid the use of .Activate It is error-prone and computationally heavy. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba for alternatives